# How to Reset or Clear UI View

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I am programming something like PONG in IOS Playgrounds.

It is all working but it is crashing after a few seconds.

I don't really know why. Can someone please help me?

The Position of the Ball is changing and The Touch Event is working but it crashes in the draw Function of the UIView

I tried to turn clear Context and all but it didn't work

```swift
import UIKit;
import PlaygroundSupport;
import CoreGraphics;
import Dispatch;

func delay (delay:Double)
{
    let t = CACurrentMediaTime()
    var b = true
    while b {
        if(CACurrentMediaTime()>t+delay){
            b=false;
            return
        }
    }
}

let page = PlaygroundPage.current

var sheight:Double = 700 //Double(UIScreen.main.bounds.height);
var swidth:Double  = 900 //Double(UIScreen.main.bounds.width);
let v = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: -100, y: -100, width: swidth, height: sheight))
swidth = Double(v.bounds.width)
sheight = Double(v.bounds.height)
let moveStab = sheight / 300;
var dirX = 1.0
var dirY = 1.0

let bsp:Double = 3.0
var Point1 = 0;
var Point2 = 0;

let psp:Double = 2.0

var up = [false,false]
var down = [false,false]

var ballx = swidth / 2;
var bally = sheight / 2;
let ballRad =  30.0
var p1x = 20.0
var p1y = sheight / 2
var p2x = swidth - 40.0
var p2y = sheight / 2
let pw = 20.0
let ph =  75.0


class Draw: UIView {
    func  PointInRad (point: CGPoint,  point2 : CGPoint, rad : CGFloat) -> Bool{
        let x1 = point.x;
        let y1 = point.y
        let x2 = point2.x
        let y2 = point2.y

        var dx = x1-x2
        var dy = y1 - y2

        if (dx < 0){dx=dx * -1}
        if (dy < 0){dy=dy * -1}

        let e = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)
        if(e <= rad){
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

    func PointInRad (point: CGPoint,  x2 : CGFloat, y2: CGFloat, rad: CGFloat) -> Bool {
        let x1 = point.x;
        let y1 = point.y

        var dx = x1-x2
        var dy = y1 - y2

        if (dx < 0){dx=dx * -1}
        if (dy < 0){dy=dy * -1}

        let e = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)
        if(e <= rad){
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

    func PointInRad ( x1 : CGFloat, y1 : CGFloat, x2 : CGFloat, y2 : CGFloat, rad: CGFloat) -> Bool{

        var dx = x1-x2
        var dy = y1 - y2

        if (dx < 0){dx=dx * -1}
        if (dy < 0){dy=dy * -1}

        let e = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)
        if(e <= rad){
            return true
        }
        return false

    }

    func update(){
        self.isMultipleTouchEnabled = true;
        self.clearsContextBeforeDrawing = true;
    }


    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        for touch in touches {

            if(PointInRad(point: touch.location(in: view), x2: 700, y2:400 , rad: 50)){
                up[1] = true
            }

            if(PointInRad(point: touch.location(in: view), x2: 100, y2:400 , rad: 50)){
                up[0] = true
            }

            if(PointInRad(point: touch.location(in: view), x2: 700, y2:500 , rad: 50)){
                down[1] = true
            }

            if(PointInRad(point: touch.location(in: view), x2: 100, y2:500 , rad: 50)){
                down[0] = true
            }
        }
    }
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches {
            if(!PointInRad(point: touch.location(in: view), x2: 700, y2:400 , rad: 50)){
                up[1] = false
            }

            if(!PointInRad(point: touch.location(in: view), x2: 100, y2:400 , rad: 50)){
                up[0] = false 
            }


            if(!PointInRad(point: touch.location(in: view), x2: 700, y2:500 , rad: 50)){
                down[1] = false
            }

            if(!PointInRad(point: touch.location(in: view), x2: 100, y2:500 , rad: 50)){
                down[0] = false
            }}

    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        for touch in touches {
            if(PointInRad(point: touch.location(in: view), x2: 700, y2:400 , rad: 50)){
                up[1] = false 
            }

            if(PointInRad(point: touch.location(in: view), x2: 100, y2:400 , rad: 50)){
                up[0] = false
            }

            if(PointInRad(point: touch.location(in: view), x2: 700, y2:500 , rad: 50)){
                down[1] = false                
            }

            if(PointInRad(point: touch.location(in: view), x2: 100, y2:500 , rad: 50)){
                down[0] = false
            }}
    }

    override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
        self.setNeedsDisplay()

    }

    var n = false;


    func drawCircle (color : UIColor, x:CGFloat, y:CGFloat, rad: CGFloat){
        // Circle Drawing
        let newx = x - rad / 2
        let newy = y - rad / 2

        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: newx, y: newy, width: rad, height: rad))

        color.setFill()
        circlePath.fill()

    }

    func drawRect ( color : UIColor, x:CGFloat, y:CGFloat, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat ) {

        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height))

        color.setFill()
        circlePath.fill()
    }


    override func draw(_: CGRect) {


        var Path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: -100, y: -100, width: 900, height: 700))
        let con = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        con?.clear(CGRect(x: -100, y: -100, width: 1000, height: 1000))

        // Color Declarations

        var color = UIColor.white;
        let ButtonN = UIColor(white: 0.5, alpha: 0.5)
        let ButtonT = UIColor(white: 0.8, alpha: 0.8)

        var p1 = NSString(string: String(Point1))
        p1.draw(in: CGRect(x: 325, y: 100, width: 75, height: 100), withAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white,NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 80) ])
        p1 = NSString(string: String(Point2))
        p1.draw(in: CGRect(x: 430, y: 100, width: 75, height: 100), withAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white,NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 80) ])

        p1 = NSString(string: String("Pong by Jakob"))
        p1.draw(in: CGRect(x: 700, y: 25, width: 100, height: 100), withAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white,NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 20) ])

        var rad = CGFloat(50);
        var newx:CGFloat = 100.0
        var newy:CGFloat = 400.0
        var circlePath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: newx, y: newy, width: rad, height: rad))

        if up[0] {
            ButtonT.setFill();
        } else {
            ButtonN.setFill();
        }
        circlePath.fill()

        circlePath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: 700, y: newy, width: rad, height: rad))

        if up[1] {
            ButtonT.setFill();
        } else {
            ButtonN.setFill();
        } 
        circlePath.fill()

        circlePath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: newx, y: 500, width: rad, height: rad))

        if down[0] {
            ButtonT.setFill();
        } else {
            ButtonN.setFill();
        }

        circlePath.fill()

        circlePath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: 700, y: 500, width: rad, height: rad))

        if down[1] {
            ButtonT.setFill();
        } else {
            ButtonN.setFill();
        } 
        circlePath.fill()

        for i in 0 ... 30 {
             color = UIColor.white

             circlePath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: CGFloat(393), y:CGFloat(Double(i)*50), width: CGFloat(14), height: CGFloat(30)))

            color.setFill()
            circlePath.fill()
        }

        circlePath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: p1x, y: p1y, width: pw, height: ph))

        color.setFill()
        circlePath.fill()

        circlePath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: p2x, y: p2y, width: pw, height: ph))

        color.setFill()
        circlePath.fill()

         rad = CGFloat(ballRad);
         color = UIColor.white;
         newx = (CGFloat(ballx) - rad / 2)
         newy =  CGFloat(bally) - rad / 2

         circlePath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: newx, y: newy, width: rad, height: rad))
        color.setFill()
        circlePath.fill()       
    }
}

let view = Draw(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: swidth, height: sheight))
view.setNeedsDisplay()
view.update()

let T = Thread(block: {

    while true {
        if(Int(ballx)<Int(p1x + pw) && bally+ballRad <= p1y + ph && bally - ballRad >= p1y){
            dirX *= -1
        }

        if(ballx<p2x && bally+ballRad <= p2y + ph && bally - ballRad >= p2y){
            dirX *= -1
        }

        if(bally < 0 + ballRad || bally > 600 - ballRad){
            dirY *= -1;
        }

        if (ballx - ballRad < 0){
            ballx = 800/2
            dirX = 1;
            Point2+=1
        }

        if (ballx + ballRad > 800){
            ballx = swidth/2
            dirX = -1;
            Point1+=1
        }

        if up[0] {
            p1y -= psp
        } 

        if up[1]{
            p2y -= psp
        }

        if down[0] {
            p1y += psp
        } 

        if down[1]{
            p2y += psp
        }

        ballx += bsp * dirX
        bally += bsp * dirY

        view.setNeedsDisplay()
        view.updateFocusIfNeeded()

        for i in 1 ... 10000 {
            print(i)      

        }
    }     
    })

T.start()

let t = Thread(block: {

    while true { 
        DispatchQueue.main.sync {

            view .setNeedsDisplay()
        }}


})

t.start()

page.liveView = view;
page.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
page.wantsFullScreenLiveView = true


Because i am on my IPad i dont have any Error message
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. There is almost 500 lines of code in your question. We cannot read all of that in order to understand what the problem is. Please only include the code that is relevant to your specific problem and break it down into multiple sections with descriptions about each. At the moment it is pretty much impossible to see what the problem is in your question.

Comment: What error logs are you seeing when it crashes?

Comment: I said i dont have any error logs

Comment: If it is crashing... then it will log out an error to the console. You can try to find the crash by adding an exception breakpoint. This will stop on the line of code that is causing the crash. But in the debug console it will be outputting an error.

Comment: No i am on my IPAD I DOnT HAVE ANY ErROR MESSAGE

Comment: if you want help from people then that is not how to get it. Good luck finding someone else who is willing to try to ask questions around this. You can help yourself with this by writing a question that makes sense and is readable. Otherwise, you’re best deleting it.